# When should we call a target using 'DependsOnTargets' and <CallTarget>?

Tags: msbuild

As far as I know, at the moment we can call other targets from within a target by using the attribute `DependsOnTargets` or by using the task `<CallTarget ...>`

My question is when should we use each case?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

MSBuild provides different ways to call target :

- [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx)
- [CallTarget task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229474.aspx)
- [DependsOnTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) target attribute
- [BeforeTargets and AfterTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) target attributes in MSBuild 4

Using `CallTarget` is an **explicit** approach, ***you*** start at your first target and call explicitly each target in the order you want.

Whereas `DependsOnTargets` is an **implicit** approach, ***MSBuild*** infers the calling order by checking the dependency of the targets.

There is no difference between `CallTarget` and `DependsOnTargets` on the number of time a target could run : **a target will never run twice during a single build** (except if you [use MSBuild task with different property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798762/all-targets-not-being-called-nested-targets-not-being-executed))

### Limitation of CallTarget

One limitation of `CallTarget` is with *dynamic items and property* : you can't access an item or a property that you have created in a target in another target called with CallTarget :

```
<Target Name="Caller">
  <CreateProperty Value="MyValue">
    <OutputTaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="NewProperty"/>
  </CreateProperty>
  <CallTarget Targets="Called"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Called">
  <Message Text="$(NewProperty)"/>
</Target>
```

Dynamic property aren't publish until the target that created them is done executing. You don't have this problem using `DependsOnTarget`

### What should I use?

You should use `DependsOnTargets` for targets that need to be executed before your target. And `CallTarget` for target to execute after your target. That's the way Microsoft do it.

```
<Target Name="CoreCompile"
        DependsOnTargets="$(CoreCompileDependsOn)">
  <!-- Target execution -->
  <Csc ... />
  ...

  <!-- Targets to execute after -->
  <CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)"/>      
</Target>
```

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. I personally try to avoid using CallTarget as much as I can, instead use DependsOnTargets.

Comment: `CallTarget` goes against the grain of MSBuild - which is to build a dependency tree of targets and run it. It's a little like using `goto` in C++.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... If the current project depends on an artifact in another project, then what is the expression we should use for `DependsOnTargets`? For example, from `Bar.vcxproj`, I can't get something like `DependsOnTargets="Project=Foo.vcxproj;Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32;` to work. And the MS docs absolutely suck. They tell me to go to [Target Element (MSBuild)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) for the discussion, then they don't discuss it.

Comment: @jonathan are there any drawbacks (other than the one in the answer) in doing this? I find `CallTarget` a lot more readable.

Answer (score -3):

The critical difference is that a target specified in DependsOnTarget **will not execute if it has already executed previously**. In this way, multiple targets can then have the same dependency, but only the first target will trigger its execution ([see MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462(v=VS.80).aspx)).

You can think of it as saying *"Make sure this target has already executed, and execute it if it hasn't."*

[CallTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229474.aspx) will just simply execute the target specified, regardless of whether it has executed previously or not.

Comment: That's not true, a target will never run twice during a single build, even using CallTarget.