# msbuild, overwriting property value in different file

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup, msbuild-target

I am trying to modify property value depending on certain condition in another file.
For ex. 
I have one file that calls target file.

```
<Import Project="sample.vcxproj"/>
<PropertyGroup>
    <Gender>Boy</Gender>
    <Search>UNIQUE_NAME</Search>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
    <callTarget Targets="SetName"/>
    <Message Text="$(Person)"/>
</Target>
```

I have one file that includes item group to decide and target that modifies

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Name Include="UNIQUE_NAME">
        <Boy>DAVID</Boy>
        <Girl>REBECCA</Girl>
    </NAME>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="SetName">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Search)'=='@(Name)'">
        <Person>@(Name->'%($(Gender))')</Person>
    </PropertyGroup>
</target>
```

But when I print 'Person' I get empty string. And I checked that 'SetName' is called and correct name is set.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the accessibility of MSBuild properties, depending on whether you are using **DependsOnTargets** or **CallTarget**. When using **DependsOnTargets** you will have greater access to properties. That is why your example works when using that method.

There is an existing [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816094/when-should-we-call-a-target-using-dependsontargets-and-calltarget) that speaks to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine using 'DependsOnTarget' attrib instead of callTarget task